# How to check undefined variable javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My Javascript is like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     var priceJson = '[{"@attributes":{"Code":"SGL","Total":"400000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"400000"}},{"@attributes":{"Code":"DBL","Total":"200000"},"DayPrice":{"Date":"2016-05-26","Rate":"200000"}}]';

    console.log(priceJson);
    var priceObject = JSON.parse(priceJson);
    console.log(priceObject);

    if(priceObject.DayPrice.Rate)
        priceObject = [priceObject]; 
    else
        priceObject = priceObject;

    console.log(priceObject);
    var priceJson = JSON.stringify(priceObject);
    console.log(priceJson);

    var countRoomType = priceObject.length;
    for(var i=0; i<countRoomType; i++){ 
        console.log(priceObject[i].DayPrice.Date);
        console.log(priceObject[i].DayPrice.Rate);
    }


</script>
```

Demo (See in console) : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/wsqdha8w/1/

Variable priceJson has a dynamic value. The value can be one single instance of data or can be an array of data. If the value contains 1 data then I convert into a data array like this:

```
if(priceObject.DayPrice.Rate)
        priceObject = [priceObject];
```

But, in console there is the following error: `TypeError: priceObject.DayPrice is undefined`

Any solutions to solve my problem?

Comment: you have error here `if(priceObject.DayPrice.Rate)`.

Comment: `if (priceObject.DayPrice && priceObject.DayPrice.Rate)..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your error message, you need to check the existance of `DayPrice` also.

```
if( priceObject.DayPrice && priceObject.DayPrice.Rate )
```

This `if` condition has two steps.

- **First** it checks if `DayPrice` exists,
- **Second** it checks if `DayPrice.Rate` exists

It won't check *second* condition if *first* one fails

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280802/how-to-change-amcharts-pie-themes

Comment: @mosestoh I haven't worked on amcharts. Not sure if I will be able to help.

Comment: No problem. Thanks