# How to change amcharts pie themes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pie-chart, amcharts

My HTML code is like this :

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 362px;"></div>
```

My Javascript code is like this :

```
var chart;
var legend;

var chartData = [
  {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9
  },
  {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1
  },
  {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8
  },
  {
    "country": "Australia",
    "litres": 139.9
  },
  {
    "country": "Austria",
    "litres": 128.3
  },
  {
    "country": "UK",
    "litres": 99
  },
  {
    "country": "Belgium",
    "litres": 60
  }
];
console.log(chartData);
AmCharts.ready(function () {
  // PIE CHART
  chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
  chart.dataProvider = chartData;
  chart.titleField = "country";
  chart.valueField = "litres";

  // WRITE
  chart.write("chartdiv");
});
```

Demo and complete code is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/4qdan7k7/2/

I want to change amchart themes like this : https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-pie-chart/

I add light.js library, but the themes not change

Any solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `theme` option while initializing as below and also make use of `makeChart` directly instead of `Amcharts.AmPieChart()`. Your updated code would be:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

## [`UPDATED FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4qdan7k7/3/)

Comment: I want ask again. How to add chart title? I want to add it as `My Chart`

Comment: @mosestoh - review this portion of the amCharts api: https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Title  Here is an updated example with a chart title: https://jsfiddle.net/dc939gzq/2/

Comment: @mg1075, Thanks. I want ask again. Every make chart, there exist `JS chart by amCharts`. What it can removed?

Comment: @mosestoh The amCharts credit line displays for non-commercial versions of the product. If you would like to remove the credit line, the proper way is to purchase the appropriate commercial version of amCharts. No credit line appears in the commercial versions. https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#creditsPosition; https://www.amcharts.com/online-store/

Comment: @mg1075, Thank you very much